# node.js promise returns nothing

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have a function which returns true if there is an user with '1' in row 'mode'. I would like to do something if '1' in row 'mode' doesn't exists.

```
function check_mod(user_id) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        db.each(`SELECT mode FROM users WHERE id = ` + user_id + ` AND mode = 1 LIMIT 1`, [], (err, row) => {
            if(err) reject(false);
            if (row.mode == 1) {
                resolve('true');
            }
        });
    });
}

check_mod('286927644405137407').then((user) => {
     console.log(user);
     console.log('ok');
}).catch((error) => {
     console.log('nie okej');
});
```

This code returns "ok" but if i change '286927644405137407' for something else, it doesn't returns "nie okej".

Comment: if row.mode != 1 it never resolves so it waits forever

Answer (score 0):

You have a path through your `db.each` callback that doesn't call `reject` *or* `resolve`, so you're never settling your promise on that path. You'd need to change

```
if (row.mode == 1) {
    resolve('true');
}
```

to

```
if (row.mode == 1) {
    resolve('true');
} else {
    reject(/*...typically you'd use new Error() here...*/);
}
```

Example, using `setTimeout` in place of `db.each`:

```js
function check_mod(user_id) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            // Fake `err` and `row`
            const err = null;
            const row = {
              mode: user_id === '286927644405137407' ? 1 : 0
            };
            // End fake
            if(err) reject(false);
            if (row.mode == 1) {
                resolve('true');
            } else {
                reject(new Error("invalid user"));
            }
        }, 100);
    });
}

check_mod('286927644405137407').then((user) => {
     console.log("first test", user);
     console.log("first test", 'ok');
}).catch((error) => {
     console.log("first test", 'nie okej');
});

check_mod('other').then((user) => {
     console.log("second test", user);
     console.log("second test", 'ok');
}).catch((error) => {
     console.log("second test", 'nie okej');
});
```

**But** there may be another problem: The name `db.each` and the parameter name `row` you're using on the `db.each` callback suggest that the callback will be called more than once (e.g., "for each row"). A promise can only be settled once, not repeatedly, so if that callback is getting called more than once, only the first will have any effect on the promise. Your SQL query has `LIMIT 1` so I assume that can't happen in **this** case, but...

Comment: I changed a code and added else and "user" returns nothing

Comment: @J.Doe - Right -- because you're rejecting, rather than resolving, and `user` only exists within the `then` handler. The `catch` handler is called instead when `user` isn't valid (if you use `reject` in the `else`).

Comment: but "not okej" is not returned either

Comment: @J.Doe - Yes, it is. See the example I added to the answer.

Comment: In your example i changed fake err and row to db.each and remove settimeout. I will check users and when i write used check_mod('other') then there is no error

Comment: @J.Doe - I'm afraid I don't know what to tell you. If you ensure that every path through the callback calls either `resolve` or `reject`, then either your `then` or `catch` handler will get called. Promises are [not broken](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips). So if you're not seeing a `then` or `catch` callback, there's a path through the `db.each` callback that doesn't call `resolve` or `reject`.

Answer (score 0):

Chris Li's comment is right. Your code just needs to handle the case when row.mode is not equal to 1.

```
db.each(`SELECT mode FROM users WHERE id = ` + user_id + ` AND mode = 1 LIMIT 1`, [], (err, row) => {
            if(err) reject(false);
            if (row.mode == 1) {
                resolve('true');
            } else {
              //resolve or reject here
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion for you: If user_id not found (I see in your query has include `AND mode = 1`)

```
        db.each(`SELECT mode FROM users WHERE id = ` + user_id + ` AND mode = 1 LIMIT 1`, [], (err, row) => {
            if(err || !row) return reject(false);
            if (row.mode == 1) {
                resolve('true');
            }
        });
```

as @T.J. Crowder answer and his comments,the reason may be your query take so long time to return result, you can reduce time out of connection to debug.